# Centering five <div> elements with a fallback for low-res screens

Tags: html, css, centering

EDIT: [JSFiddle link of what I have right now](http://jsfiddle.net/LWP5V/)

I'm trying to design a webpage that with a header like this: [(imgur link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFuzX.png).

Basically I want a centered logo, with five (or more) links just below it. Here's where it gets tricky: I'd like to match up the center link to the exact width of the logo image, and have the other four links float off to the left and right sides.

So far I have

```
<div id="logoDiv">
    <img id="logo" src="resources/images/logo.png" alt="logo image" width="300" height="138">
</div>

<div id="mainMenu" style="text-align:center;">

    <div class="mainMenuDiv" style="">
        <a class="menuItem" href="1.html">link 1</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mainMenuDiv" style="">
        <a class="menuItem" href="2.html">link 2</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mainMenuDiv" id="mainMenuCenter" style="">
        <a class="menuItem" id="mainMenuItem" href="index.html">centered main link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mainMenuDiv" style="">
        <a class="menuItem" href="4.html">link 4</a>
    </div>
    <div class="mainMenuDiv" style="">
        <a class="menuItem" href="5.html">link 5</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

But no matter what I put in the stylesheet (or the now blank style tags), I can't get the five divs to always have the center one exactly centered independent of screen resolution. Using display:indent-block; and float:left||right; I managed to get close, but when the screen isn't wide enough I end up with links 1 &&/|| 2 under the logo which looks terrible.

Should I not put all of them in a container? Should I just give in and try to position them with javascript? I'm pretty new to HTML/CSS programming and I'm not really sure what the correct approach is here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: produce the fiddle to make it more clear...

Comment: I can give a plug to Twitter Bootstrap, which employs a grid system that could simplify this task greatly.

Comment: I've added what I have to JSFiddle, although it doesn't work (not sure why, like I said I'm not to this). Chris: Thanks, I'll give that a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a media query to display the content how you want it on a small screen.  Example:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LWP5V/2/

```
.mainMenuItemDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 19%;
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    .mainMenuItemDiv {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logoDiv">
        <img id="logo" src="" alt="Logo"/>
    </div>

    <div id="mainMenu">
       <div class="mainMenuItemDiv">
            <a class="menuItem" href="1.html">1</a>
        </div>

        <div class="mainMenuItemDiv">
            <a class="menuItem" href="2.html">2</a>
        </div>

        <div class="mainMenuItemDiv" id="mainMenuCenter">
            <a class="menuItem" href="index.html">Three</a>
        </div>

        <div class="mainMenuItemDiv">
            <a class="menuItem" href="4.html">4</a>
        </div>

        <div class="mainMenuItemDiv">
            <a class="menuItem" href="5.html">5</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper
{
    margin:0px auot;
    width:500px;
}
#logoDiv {
    text-align:center;
    width:500px;

}

#mainMenu {
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px;
      text-align:center;
        width:500px;
        display:inline-block;
    }

.mainMenuItemDiv {
            display:inline-block;
            width:100px;
            float:left;
}
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:14pt;
    color:red;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Hs7z7/1/)

Comment: Resize this to 400px wide and you'll see the center one is no longer centered and the right ones are cut off.  This is not what the OP asked for.